# How to get directory of hosting environment .net core 2 to upload file

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have deployed a .NET core 2 web application to IIS on a Microsoft 2016 server and I can't upload files now (a regular functionality working in DEV).
I have looked through a bunch of solutions and none work.

Here is my upload code:
var path = Path.Combine(ROOT, "/uploads", FileName);

For ROOT:

Directory.GetCurrentDirectory: doesn't work properly on the server. It defaults to the C: drive (This works in DEV)

HostingEnvironment.MapPath: Apparently HostingEnvironment doesn't contain a definition for MapPath

HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath: Apparently HttpContext doesn't contain a definition for Current

Does anyone know what I could do?
This .net core 2 framework has honestly been an uphill battle with everything compared to the .net framework.

Thanks!

Comment: Does your program.cs file have `.UseContentRoot(...)`? You should set the content root of your project correctly so you can use relative paths throughout your code rather than having to combine the full path. For getting the directory of your application try `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`.

Comment: You can use IHostingEnvironment WebRoot property. https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/05/22/getting-the-web-root-path-and-the-content-root-path-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I, as usual, was led on a wild goose chase when the code for the path was correct.
This was the code I was using to upload:

var stream1 = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

It needed to be:

var stream1 = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);